Dell Venue 11 Pro (7139?) - No resume from S3 sleep?
I have an issue with my old Dell Venue 11 Pro (7139, I think?). It does not resume from deep sleep when I press suspend.
When I enter cat /sys/power/mem_sleep then my two options are s2idle [deep] however I have to switch to s2idle as it does not resume from sleep otherwise.
How can I debug or resolve this? As I am getting huge battery drain due to the sleep mode it is in.
